# Fun example of representations of $sl_2(\mathbb C)$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

What are fun occurence of $sl_2(\mathbb C)$ representations "in nature"? Ideally elementary examples would be the best.

Examples I know :

The cohomology ring $H^*(X,\mathbb C)$ for $X \subset \mathbb P^n$ smooth projective is such an example but definitely not elementary. I think some variant should work as well (e.g $X$ compact symplectic).

The double coinvariant ring $\mathbb C[\underline{x},\underline{y}]/ (\mathbb C[\underline{x},\underline{y}]^W_+)$ (where $\underline x = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$, same for $y$ and $W = S_n$) is another example but again it's not that elementary.

The ring $\mathbb C[x,y]$, where the action comes from $SL_2(\mathbb C)$ acting on $\mathbb C^2$ (so $sl_2(\mathbb C)$ acts as vector fields).

Any other examples are welcome, especially if it's outside representation theory (combinatorics, geometry, topology,...)

Comment: Does "in nature" include physics? Because that would of course intersect with representation theory, geometry and topology (of the universe...).

Comment: @DietrichBurde : I guess there are many examples from physics. I'lI l still be happy to read about it but I was thinking to mathematical examples if possible.

Comment: Yes, this kind of physics mostly is mathematics. The problem is your requirement, it should be *outside* of representation theory, geometry and topology (and combinatorics!). Also the answer below belongs to representation theory (unitary representations) and is used in physics.

Comment: @DietrichBurde : I'm sorry, maybe I should be not so rigid about these requirements. I would be very happy to see about your example.

Comment: @downvoter : would you like to leave a comment so I could improve my question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One classic is the Segal-Shale/oscillator representation of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ on various spaces of functions on $\mathbb R^n$ by sending
$$
\pmatrix{0 & 1 \cr 0 & 0} \to (\hbox{multiplication by}) {|x|^2\over 2}
\hskip30pt
\pmatrix{0 & 0 \cr 1 & 0} \to {\Delta\over 2}
\hskip30pt
\pmatrix{1 & 0 \cr 0 & -1} \to {n\over 2} + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i{\partial\over \partial x_i}
$$

Comment: Looks quite nice !

Answer (score 2):

The [Fractional quantum Hall effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_quantum_Hall_effect) in physcis is strongly related to the Langlands program in automorphic forms within number theory, with the group $G=SL_2(\Bbb C)$ and its Langlands dual $G^L=PSL_2(\Bbb C)$ with their Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}\cong \mathfrak{g}^L\cong \mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C)$ and their irreducible representations. This is, for example, explained in the article [Topological Aspects of Matters and Langlands Program](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.11879) by Kazuki Ikeda.

Comment: This is great!${}$

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** "What are fun occurence of sl2(C) representations "in nature"? Ideally elementary examples would be the best."

**Answer:** If $k$ is a field and $V:=k\{e_0,e_1\}, V^*:=k\{x_0,x_1\}$, let $C:=\mathbb{P}(V^*)$ be the projective line on $V$. The tangent sheaf $T_C$ has global sections

$$H^0(C,T_C) \cong H^0(C,\mathcal{O}_C(2)) \cong \mathfrak{sl}(2,k).$$

The tangent sheaf is a "sheaf of Lie algebras" and its global sections is a $k$-Lie algebra isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}(2,k)$.If $D_C$ is the sheaf of differential operators on $C$ and if $E$ is a left $D_C$-module you get a left $\mathfrak{sl}(2,k)$-module structure on $H^0(C,E)$. This gives a functor

$$F: D_C-mod \rightarrow U(\mathfrak{sl}(2,k))-mod.$$

The global sections $H^0(C, \mathcal{O}(d)) \cong Sym^d(V^*)$ is canonically an $U(\mathfrak{sl}(2,k))$-module. This comes from the fact that there is a parabolic subgroup $P \subseteq SL(V)$ and an isomorphism $SL(V)/P \cong C$. The linebundle $\mathcal{O}(d)$ has an $SL(V)$-linearization inducing the $SL(V)$-module structure $Sym^d(V^*)$ on the vector space of global sections.
This is the Borel-Weil-Bott theorem: Any finite dimensional irreducible $SL(V)$-module arise as the global sections of some inverible sheaf on $C$.

All constructions are elementary and may be "written out in detail by hand".

**Fun for students:** This example is "fun" for students: They can interpret elements in $\mathfrak{sl}(2,k)$ as algebraic vector fields on $C$ and make explicit calculations.

Comment: I was already aware of this answer and I mentioned it ($\mathbb C[x,y] = \bigoplus_n \Gamma(P^1, O(n))$, where $sl_2$ also acts as vector field)

Comment: @student - The above is "more general" in the sense that it gives an action on $H^0(C,E)$ for any $D_C$-module $E$. Note that $T_C$ acts on $\mathcal{O}_C$: For any open affine set $U \subseteq C$ it follows $T_C(U) \cong Der_k(\mathcal{O}(U))$ is the Lie algebra of derivations of $\mathcal{O}(U)$. Hence the above is "sheaf theoretic" and gives non-trivial elementary examples for students in algebraic geometry.

Comment: @student - The example you give in the post is the "trivial" example $\oplus_d Sym^d(V^*)$.

Comment: As it stands this is a very very complicated way of saying “the action on a polynomial ring in two variables”. I appreciate that you might be able to get more interesting modules out of the sheaf-theoretic framework, are you able to name a few?

Comment: @Joppy - The invertible sheaves $\mathcal{O}(d)$ on $C$ are not $D_C$-modules for $d\in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence I'm not so sure one may give "elementary" examples coming from sheaves. On $C$ any locally trivial sheaf $E$ of finite rank is a direct sum $E \cong \oplus_{i=1}^l \mathcal{O}(d_i)$. Hence $E$ is not a $D_C$-module.

Comment: @Joppy: As it stands this is a very very complicated way of saying “the action on a polynomial ring in two variables” - I agree this may be confusing. We use this notation to "remember" that the action of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,k):=\mathfrak{sl}(V)$ comes from the natural action of $SL(V)$ on $V$. We start with a vector space $V$, then construct the group $SL(V)$ and the action on $C$ and $\mathcal{O}(d)$. This induce a canonical action on $H^0(C, \mathcal{O}(d))\cong Sym^d(V^*)$  - we take the symmetric power of the $SL(V)$-module $V^*$. Here we must dualize.

Comment: @Joppy -for $V \cong k^2$ it follows $V \cong V^*$ as $SL(V)$-modules but this is not true in general. Hence if we do not dualize we make mistakes.

Comment: I agree with Joppy, do you have other examples of $sl_2$modules constructed from the $D_C$-module viewpoint?